# Increasing the spacing between table rows

Tags: html, css

The code below works all fine and dandy.  However, I would like to put a space of maybe 16 pixels / one row height between each row pair shown below.  How can I do this?  I think this might be a CSS issue.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename1"><a href="http://www.'.$row["url"].'">'.$row["title"].'</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename2"><a href="http://www.'.$row["url"].'">'.$row["loginid"].'</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: Tackle problems in isolation: This has nothing to do with PHP :)

Comment: Duly noted; I removed the PHP tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add padding to the `td`s in question:

```
.sitename1 {padding-bottom:16px}
```